# Printer driver - Java preprocessor detect options selected?

Tags: java, windows, printing, redmon

We have written a Java application that accepts on stdin a postscript stream. This stream is redirected by RedMon from a print job the user has selected in Windows.

Trouble is, the printer options include duplex and colour. In the Java application, we don't get to see what has been selected.

The Java application's job is to allow specific options to be chosen including a preview, then to send the "job" on to a web service that will further process the "job".

Can anything think how to detect if duplex or single-sided, or back and white or colour, has been chosen within the printer options?

Comment: What is that PS stream? Does it contain the PPD?

Comment: The Postscript Printer Definition? My understanding is this is a description of the device's capabilities that Windows then turns into an inf file somehow. I'm not aware of any way of detecting what is in the postscript stream itself. Indeed, we take the postscript and use Ghostscript to immediately turn it into a PDF which is then read into PDFBox.